# Restricting resource routes and adding additional non-RESTful routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I wasn't able to find anything here or elsewhere that covered both restricting a resource's routes and adding additional non-RESTful routes in Rails 3. It's probably very simple but every example or explanation I've come across addresses just one case not both at the same time.

Here's an example of what I've been doing in Rails 2:

`map.resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy], :member => {:recovery => :get}`

Pretty straightforward, we only want 3 of the 7 RESTful routes because the others don't make any sense for this resource, but we also want to add another route which is used in account recovery.

Now from what I gather doing either one of these things is very straightforward as well:

`resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]`

Just like in Rails 2. And:

```
resources :sessions do
  member do
    get :recovery
  end
end
```

So, how do I combine these two? Can I still use the old Rails 2 way of doing this? Is there a preferred way of doing this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass arguments and a block to `resources`:

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy] do
  get :recovery, :on => :member
end
```

And test it out with `rake routes`.

Comment: My `routes.rb` declares `resources :thing, :only => [:show] do get :foo, :on => :member end`, and `rakes routes` gives `foo_thing GET /thing/foo(.:format) thing#foo` plus `thing GET /thing(.:format) thing#show`.  The link to `thing` works, but if the code navigates to link `foo_thing`, I get a Rails "Routing Error" screen that says `No route matches [GET] "/foo_thing"` -- though if I type `.../thing/foo` into the URL bar, it works. (The path `foo_thing` works from within the code only if `routes.rb` has the line `get 'foo_thing' => 'thing#foo'`). Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I expanded on my question above, and wrote [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597382/helper-path-generated-by-rails-based-on-a-custom-rest-method-fails), so if you have an answer, could you please go to it? Kthxbye.

Answer (score 5):

It should be working pretty much like this

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy] do
  member do
    get :recovery
  end
end
```

There is an even shorter way, as proposed by coreyward.

Check the rails guides, "[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)".
I also can recommend "The Rails 3 Way" by Obie Fernandez, which got 2 pretty good chapters on Routing and RESt.

Cheers

Comment: You've got a typo on "resources". ;)

Comment: Remove the comma before the `do` at the end of the first line, and this will be correct.