# Adding methods to REST rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I want to add more methods to my rest.

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
 resources :boards, :except => [:new, :create] do
   get 'customize', :on => :member
   get 'change_template', :on => :member
   get 'all_walls', :on => :member
end
```

I am getting them in the following format:

```
change_template_board GET    /boards/:id/change_template(.:format)          {:action=>"change_template", :controller=>"boards"}
```

But I want them in this format:

```
/boards/:board_id/change_template/:id(.:format)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying the first answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404604/restricting-resource-routes-and-adding-additional-non-restful-routes-in-rails-3).  In your `routes.rb`, you can add a new route `dooit` to resource `fifi` by adding this to your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :fifi do
  member do
    get :dooit
  end
end
```

This will create the route `dooit_fifi` along with the standard `fifi`, `fifi_index`, `new_fifi`, and `edit_fifi` routes.

If you want to restrict the routes created, you can do something like this:

```
resources :fifi, only: [:show, :create, :destroy] do
  member do
    get :dooit
  end
end
```

which will produce only the routes `dooit_fifi`, `fifi`, and `fifi_index`.