# helper path generated by Rails based on a custom REST method fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

wanted to define custom routes into certain resources in addition to the ones Rails defines by default.  To do this, the relevant parts of my `routes.rb` file look something like this:

```
resource :top, only: [:show]
scope module: :top do
  resource :reso, only: [:show]
end

get 'foo_reso' => 'top/reso#foo'
get 'bar_reso' => 'top/reso#bar'
```

As you can see, I only want routes to `ResoController`'s methods `show`, `foo`, and `bar`.  This works, as `rake routes` gives:

```
    reso GET    /reso(.:format)           top/reso#show
foo_reso GET    /foo_reso(.:format)       top/reso#foo
bar_reso GET    /bar_reso(.:format)       top/reso#bar
```

This works: clicking on a link in the application that takes you to the route `foo_reso` does result in a call `ResoController#foo`, and the subsequent display of the associated view.

However, I thought that the route definition was just slightly ugly, and instead of defining the routes explicity, wanted Rails to generate them automatically by telling it that the resource has two additional REST methods, `foo` and `bar` (while still restricting the standard methods by means of the `only:` argument).

I followed the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404652/351716), and changed `routes.rb` to this:

```
resource :top, only: [:show]
scope module: :top do
  resource :reso, only: [:show] do
    member do
      get :foo
      get :bar
    end
  end
end
```

Now, `rake routes` gives:

```
    reso GET    /reso(.:format)           top/reso#show
foo_reso GET    /reso/foo(.:format)       top/reso#foo
bar_reso GET    /reso/bar(.:format)       top/reso#bar
```

Note the difference between the paths in the two cases: while the helper path and the controller#action are the same, the path has changed from `/foo_reso(.:format)` to `/reso/foo(.:format)`.

(I have all the resource names defined as uncountable in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`, so I don't get automatic pluralization of the names, because in my application, each controller is associated with a particular screen, not with a model, so pluralization doesn't fit the picture. In this app, the REST methods are really more like function calls than operations on a resource, which is why I need a different set than the standard.)

Now, clicking on a link to `foo_reso` in the application results in a Rails routing error page that says:

```
No route matches [GET] "/foo_reso"
```

Any ideas on what I could do to fix the situation, aside from just using my original solution?

**Added on edit, 2013-07-12:**

As I note in a comment below, according to the output of `rake routes`, the helper route `foo_reso` matches the controller and method I want to call, `top/reso#foo`, **and** when I manually enter the matching URL (`reso/foo`) into the URL bar, that works as intended.  However, trying to open the route `foo_reso` from within the application results in a `No route matches [GET] "/foo_reso"`.  `foo_reso_path` and `foo_reso_url` result in the same error.

What on earth can the problem be?  Surely not a bug in Rails?

**Added on edit, 2013-07-22:**

To make the use case a bit clearer, the idea is that when the user presses a "Reset" button on a page, the controller's `reset` method is called, which clears the page's inputs and outputs. I have been abstracting the question by changing the actual identifier `reset` to `foo`. (`reso` and and a couple of other identifiers are also the result of "obfuscation".)  I'll continue to use the same translations for consistency's sake, but the code below should be clearer when you bear in mind that `foo` is actually `reset`. (`bar` is something else, but it doesn't matter, since the routing problem is the same.)

To answer Thong Kuah's and John Hinnegan's questions, this is how I use `foo_reso_path`.  The relevant parts of file `reso_controller`:

```
class Top::ResoController < Top::ResoSuperController

  # GET /reso
  def show
    ...
    @reset_path = "foo_reso"
    ...
  end # show

  # GET /foo_reso
  def foo
    perform_foo_action
    redirect_to reso_path
  end
  ...
end
```

The relevant parts of file `app/views/top/reso/show.html.erb`:

```
<%= render partial: "top/resosuper_inputs", locals: { the_form_path: reso_path } %>
...
<input type="hidden" id="reset_path" name="reset_path" value="<%= @reset_path %>">
```

The form includes the partial `_resosuper_inputs.html.erb`, whose relevant parts are:

```
<!-- For using the "Reset" button. -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "my_reset_form.js" %>
<%= simple_form_for :filtering_criteria, url: the_form_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  ... inputs elided ...
  <%= f.button :submit, value: "Search" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, type: 'button', value: "Reset"), id: 'reset_button' %>
<% end %>
```

`resosuper` is the superclass of two different resources, but I don't think that has any effect on the case. Anyway, here's the Javascript file `app/assets/javascripts/my_reset_form.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Hang functionality on the "Reset" button. */
  $('#reset_button').click(function () {
      var reset_path = $('#reset_path').val();
      window.open(reset_path, "_self")
  });
})
```

It's in jQuery, and as the comment says, makes the "Reset" button open the path whose value has been stored in the hidden input variable with the id `reset_path`.  That value is what was given to the form by `Top::ResoController` in the variable `@reset_path`, namely, `"foo_reso"`.

Keep in mind that all this worked fine when I defined `foo_reso` in `routes.rb` like this:

```
get 'foo_reso' => 'top/reso#foo'
```

Also keep in mind that replacing `foo_reso` with `foo_reso_path` or with `foo_reso_url` in the assignment statement in `ResoController` made no difference.

The places where I use `foo_reso` are in a controller and in a view, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your previous endpoint URLs were incorrect. If they are actions on the  "reso" resource, then they should be namespaced under that resource. If you were not limiting to just :show, you would URLs like /reso, /reso/123, /reso/new. That's how REST endpoint URLs work.

Comment: OK, I guess a part of the trouble I'm having stems from what I said in the parenthetical remark: I'm trying to use the "resources" in a non-standard way. Basically, I want the routes to trigger method calls in a controller. In this case, the resources that controllers are associated with are not models, but rather screens. (The app is a GUI to a Java EE application that handles the actual resources.)

Comment: I think you're getting a little lost in the weeds on translating this over from the Java space. Your controller can worry about translating your URL over to some resource on the Java app. The controller method that would have been called from the routes listing is "top/reso#foo", which translates to Top::Reso.foo in your controller. Every member you add will work like that.

Comment: As an example, if you have screens for adding widgets to a user and for getting a report on the user's widgets, you might have members on the :user resource for :addwidgets and :widgetreports. That will give you URLs like /user/123/addwidgets and /user/123/widgetreports, that go to UserController.addwidgets and UserController.widgetreports. And inside those methods in the controller, you can call over to the Java app.

Comment: Actually, what my Ruby code is doing is what you suggested: `foo`, `bar`, etc. are **not** Java classes or Java resources; rather, they are `Reso` functions that construct REST calls to the Java code, based on user input to forms in the screen associated with `ResoController`. My problem is that when I try to make `foo` into a REST method, the route `foo_reso` fails, even though `rake routes` shows that it matches the controller and action I want (`top/reso#foo`), and even though when I type into the URL bar the URI (`/reso/foo`) that `rake routes` gives for it, it works as intended.

Comment: I also tried `foo_reso_path` and `foo_reso_uri` in the code, but they fall in the same way: Rails says that "No route matches".

Comment: Can you please post your usage of `foo_reso_path` in your views please ? Surely `foo_reso_path` should generate a path of `/reso/foo` ?!

Comment: Something is still up with your example. In your second routes file example, by doing actions on a member, Rails will generate routes with an id in them somewhere. To get them called generically that would have to be collection.

Comment: From where are you calling `foo_reso_path`. The route helpers are only automatically loaded in the controllers and views.

Comment: @Thong Kuah: for the calling code, see my addition to the question. Yes, according to `rake routes`, `foo_reso_path` **does** generate the path `/reso/foo`, **and** typing that path directly in the URL bar **does** work. That's why I'm so puzzled why neither `foo_reso` nor `foo_reso_path` work in the code.

Comment: @John Hinnegan: for the calling code, see my addition to the question. I'm using the path only in a controller and in a view (or rather, tried to use many such path, but only in controllers and views). I see your point about a collection, but remember, typing `http://localhost:3000/reso/foo` directly in the browser's URL bar **does** work, nor does `rake routes` display an ID to be given in the path.

Comment: @John Hinnegan: the reason why I don't need to use the plural form of `reso` in the path, nor do I need to define an ID, is that I've defined all the resource names as uncountable in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.  (See the question for more details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the description, here is the "usage".

```
# GET /reso
def show
...
  @reset_path = "foo_reso"
...
end # show
```

However, all the above is doing is just setting the `@reset_path` instance variable into a literal string `"foo_reso" (which coincidentally matches the old route)

What the poster really wants is :

```
 @reset_path = foo_reso_path
```

which will generate the right path `/reso/foo` into the instance variable `@reset_path`

Sidenote: The poster has done all the right things here to debug route problems. Most of the time, you can trust `rake routes`. Checking that one can access the route directly is good, and so is checking the usage of the route helper is correct too is crucial

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is no automatic way in Rails to do so.

The reason is that RESTul URL relies basically on the format `/controller/action`. Meaning if your controller `ResoController` has 3 methods `show`, `foo`, and `bar`, a correct restful implementation will result in the URLS:

```
/reso
/reso/foo
/reso/bar
```

Rails can help you do achieve this, and the solution is using `members` in your routes, exactly the way you described in your question.

Using URLs such as `/foo_reso` or `/bar_reso` - in other words `/action_controller` is not Rails standard, and Rails base philosophy is "convention over configuration". So if you really need those you must declare them by hand

Comment: Actually, as I just found out, there **is** an automatic way to define paths to resources using custom REST methods. You're correct in that you can't define an **URL** such as `/foo_reso`, but defining a custom REST method `foo` on resource `reso` **does** automatically define a **path** `foo_reso`, which is then translated into the URL `/reso/foo`, whose invocation is converted into a call on the method `ResoController#foo` -- provided I define `reso` as an uncountable in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`; if not, substitute `resos` and `ResosController` as needed.

Comment: Well yes, that's exactly what I wrote `/reso/foo` = RESTful can be done automaticaly --- `/foo_reso` = not RESTful must be done manually

Comment: Again, you're correct if you mean the **URL** `/foo_reso`, but I wanted the **named route** `foo_reso` to work "automatically", after having defined a custom REST method `foo` on resource `reso`, and this is what I (finally) accomplished. (I've used the term "path" inconsistently in my question and comments; for instance, I wrote "path" in the comment above when I should have said "named route", so this exchange might be due to me mangling the terminology.)

Comment: Actually, [the Rails Routing from the Outside In guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) calls them "route helpers" instead.  So, when you command `rake routes`, you get three columns: route helpers, URLs, and controller#actions.

Comment: Did you try `as:`? in your route file `get :foo, as: 'reset'` and see the output of `rake routes`

Comment: Do you mean, tried to add such a line in `routes.rb` separate from the `resource :reso` definition? No, I didn't try that, and am not going to, because what I was trying to (and did) accomplish was to be able to define custom REST actions (`foo`, `bar`, etc.) **in** the `resource :reso` definition, and have those definitions produce the same kinds of route helpers (`foo_reso`, etc.) that the standard rails REST methods (`new`, `delete`, etc.) come with (`new_reso`, etc.).

Comment: You are missing the point `as: 'blah'` will generate a `blah_url` helper, that may be your solution ... if you are curious

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Could you please provide the entire definition you're suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out the problem. As often turns out to be the case after digging into a seemingly mysterious bug, the solution was very simple. My `reso_controller.rb` was:

class Top::ResoController < Top::ResoSuperController

```
# GET /reso
def show
  ...
  @reset_path = "foo_reso"
  ...
end # show
```

I replaced the assignment line by this:

```
  @reset_path = foo_reso_path
```

**without** quotes around `foo_reso_path`.  Now the "Reset" button works as intended.

In summary, the following **don't** work:

```
  @reset_path = "foo_reso"
  @reset_path = "foo_reso_path"
  @reset_path = "foo_reso_url"
  @reset_path = foo_reso
```

And the following **do** work:

```
  @reset_path = foo_reso_path
  @reset_path = foo_reso_url
```

Don't I feel silly now. Sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to say that :) A string is not equal to a route helper method

Comment: If you were just about to say it, submit it as an answer, and I'll award you the bounty.